# Quickest way to do n/(n+m) on a 4-function calculator

Tags: calculator

Let's say the problem I want to solve is:

I have n "widgets" and m "doodads".  I want to know what percentage of the total items are widgets.

Let's say I only have a basic 4-function calculator (+-*/) (maybe or maybe not having  memory buttons, i.e. M+, M-, MR).

Questions:

1. Is there any way to do this in a single calculation? (I don't think so)
2. If not, what is the easiest (i.e. fewest number of keystrokes) way to do this?
3. Can it be done without having to write down or remember an intermediate value?
4. Can I do #3 it without having to enter either of the numbers (n or m) more than once?

My best solutions so far using memory buttons:

#3:
n + m = M+ C n / MR =

#4:
n M+ + m = / MR = MC M+ C 1 / MR =

They're both kind of a lot of keystrokes. Any better ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on how your calculator works, but does `m / n + 1 M+ C 1 / MR =` do the trick? The idea is to write $\frac{n}{n+m}$ as $\frac1{1 + \frac mn}$.

Comment: Nice trick! I didn't think about changing the equation that way.